# PySNMP how to convert to dot oid

Tags: pysnmp

How to convert in python SNMPv2-SMI.enterprises.9.1.283 to dot oid?

SNMPv2-SMI.enterprises.9.1.283 -> 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.283

Thanks,
Alexey

Answer (score 1):

You can get usufal data by:

```
print(o.getLabel())
print(o.getMibNode())
print(o.getMibSymbol())
print(o.getOid())
print(o.prettyPrint())
```

Answer (score 0):

pysnmp implementation to resolve mib names to OID

```
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, rfc1902, error
mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)
mibVar = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-SMI', 'enterprises', 9, 1, 283)
mibVar.resolveWithMib(mibView)
print(mibVar.prettyPrint())  # prints SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.1.283
print(tuple(mibVar)) # prints (1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 9, 1, 283)
print(str(mibVar)) # prints 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.283
```

[Reference](https://pysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/pysnmp-hlapi-tutorial.html)